# Routes are simultaneously valid, yet broken

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I asked a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57414340/routing-for-a-default-document-in-mvc5-eliminating-action-from-url), in which I attempted to use a blank URL to catch a default page.

After some more digging, and some trial and error, I stumbled upon the use of `{*url}` to catch the root URL. I also attempted to use a constraint to manage the "tidy" url that I want to use. My RouteConfig now looks like so:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "LoginRoute",
                url: "{login}",
                defaults: new { controller = "LoginController", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                constraints: new { login = "login" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{*url}",
                defaults: new { controller = "authController", action = "routingsuccess" }
            );
```

However, neither of these routes result in a web page. Instead, they still result in 404. Curiously, however, Phil Haack's RouteDebugger reports that the URL I am using is valid, as demonstrated here:

[image: Route failure]

To clarify, accessing the root url (in this case, `localhost:3000`) results in the same issue.

There is a valid controller, and a valid view behind it with the appropriate action. What could possibly be wrong?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 As in, `Routeconfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);`? If so, yes

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 In `RouteConfig.cs`, within `RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 That's a thing? I'm assuming in brackets immediately prior to the action?

Comment: Yes, here's [an article on mvc5 routing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/).

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I will keep this in mind. Is there a problem with my conventional approach as-is?

Comment: Without a broader view of your application, I can't really say for certain.  I've seen this behavior on older versions, but never really found the cause and just dealt with default routing behavior.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 How broad are we talking?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the normal default routing.

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "authController", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

This just mean, if a controller isn't passed in the url then it will use MainController. If an action isn't passed then it will use Index. This mean http://website.com will go to MainController action Index.

Comment: Unfortunately, this results in the same issue. I need the default URL to point to an authentication tester, which will test for an AD membership or a recognised device. That controller is called `authController`. Setting the default route up with the URL parameter that you suggested only works if I append `auth` to the URL - I.E. `http://localhost:3000/auth` in my case.

Comment: If you set the default controller to authController then it will go to that controller.

Comment: I have trouble looking at the image. Can you remove all routes and keep this one?

Comment: No change. Would a different image host help?

Comment: Is authController in the right namespace? Does it have same case for each characters?

Comment: Yep. If they weren't, I wouldn't be able to load the page from `<url>/auth`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using [Authorise] attribute, or something else for authentication.
I will just make a guess : - 
Your route is registred, and there is no problem in it. Problem occurs when you try to access it. There might be some kind of authorisation, like an [Authorise] attribute, that would block non access users to get to your route. 
Or there might be something else, that would be causing your code to not be able to reach the ActionResult.
To confirm this, put a breakpoint in the constructor of the COntroller.Remove all attributes from the COntroller. If your debugger stops at the breakpoint in constructor, then the issue is not is registering the route, but access related.
Let me know if it helps.

Comment: I see your line of thinking, but I'm not using any of the boilerplate auth solutions. Actually, nothing is coded yet - I literally just have `<p>Success!<p>` in the view.